# Calculate If Date Is Every Other Friday And If So Do Something

Tags: vb.net, date

So I need to know how I can grab every other Friday starting with the date of a Friday, have the program check if the date is one of those dates and if so do X function. So far I found how to find the Friday after one Friday, but I need it to gather up the dates and save them then check against them.

```
Dim payday as Date= GetNext(DayOfWeek.Friday) 

Function GetNext(ByVal d As DayOfWeek, Optional ByVal StartDate As Date = Nothing) As Date
    If StartDate = DateTime.MinValue Then StartDate = Now
    For p As Integer = 1 To 7
        If StartDate.AddDays(p).DayOfWeek = d Then Return StartDate.AddDays(p)
    Next
End Function
```

Then Here is the If Statement I am thinking of

```
If Date.Today = payday Then
    'do this
End If
```

Rough sketch of what I was thinking.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim startDate As Date 'fill with an initial Friday
Function IsPayday(Optional dte as Date? = Nothing) As Boolean
    dte = If(dte, Today)
    Return DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, startDate, dte) Mod 14 = 0
End Function
```

and use it:

```
Dim yesterday = Today.AddDays(-1)
If IsPayday(yesterday) Then
    'yesterday was a pay day
End If
If IsPayday() Then
    'today is a pay day
End If
```

Comment: If it was an extension, it might be even better for how it seems like the OP will use it: `If thisDate.IsPayDay() Then...`

Comment: @Plutonix I feel that the determination of a PayDay is a business logic rule, not something globally appropriate, and therefore should not be an extension to `Date`. But that is up to the OP.

Comment: And then test date could just be set up as date.today to pull today's date right?

Comment: And to check if the day is not an every other Friday from 8/28/2015 I can just do if not ispayday(testdate) then, correct?

Comment: @Morrg Yes. See the [If..Then..Else](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx) statement and the [Not](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cwcswt4.aspx) operator.